# How to correctly invoke big logic in another Thread/Task?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library

Here is my problem, I got a WCF project, which doesnt really matter in fact because it's more about C#/.NET I believe. In my WCF Service when client is requestinq one of the methods I make the validation of the input, and if it succeeds I start some business logic calculactions. I want to start this logic in another thread/task so after the input validation I can immediately return response. Its something like this:

```
XXXX MyMethod(MyArgument arg)
{
     var validation = _validator.Validate(arg);
     if (validation.Succeed)
     {
         Task.Run(() => businessLogic())
     }    

     return MyResponseModel();
}
```

I need to make it like this because my buesinessLogic can take long time calculactions and database saves in the end, but client requesting the Service have to know immediately if the model is correct.

In my businessLogic calculactions/saves that will be running in background thread I have to catch exceptions if something fail and save it in database. (its pretty big logic so many exceptions can be thrown, like for example after calculactions im persisting the object in the database so save error can be thrown if database is offline for example)

How to correctly implement/what to use for such a requirements? I am just giving consideration if using Task.Run and invoking all the logic in the action event is a good practice?

Comment: Task.Run is usually the wrong appproach, it won't scale. Investigate [threading in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23912456/60761) or use a (Azure) Message Queue .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

Be aware, though, that worker processes can exit at any time. In that case outstanding work will simply be lost. Maybe you should queue the work to a message queue instead.

Also, if the task "crashes" you will not be notified in any way. Implement your own error logging.

Also, there is no limit to the number of tasks that you can spawn like this. If processing is too slow more and more work will queue up. This might not at all be a problem if you know that the server will not be overloaded.

It was suggested that `Task.Run` will use threads and therefore not scale. This is not necessarily so. Usually, the bottleneck of any processing is not the number of threads but the backend resources being used (database, disk, services, ...). Even using hundreds of threads is not in any way likely to be a bottleneck. Async IO is not a way around backend resource constraints.

Comment: You do not account for WCF being a (ASP.NET) service, this interferes with thread maangement etc. But you are right about it being unreliable.